# how to restart php on windows server 2008 without restarting the whole server

Tags: windows-server-2008, php

Hi I want to restart PHP so that it will load any new extensions without restarting the whole server. I have to install a web app I made along with the extensions it needs on an older server running Windows Server 2008 R2 that contains other apps that are being used which means I cannot restart the whole server.

Is there a command or something that will reload php on the server without shutting off the entire server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restart your webserver, probably IIS (`iisreset` in an elevated command prompt or PowerShell), for PHP changes to take effect.

Obligatory warning: Windows Server 2008 R2 will be EOL from 14.01.2020.

Comment: thx and thx for the obligatory warning, lol.  My boss is making me use that server but he said it was being upgraded soon